# Search for a pattern within a line and copy the same line and insert it right under that line

Tags: python

if file 1 has 4 lines of text, for example

```
 I was born in vizag
 I love python
 I am 22 years old
 I am not an experienced programmer
```

If these are the 4 lines and if the pattern that I searched for is "love", the desired output in *file 2* should be like this

```
 I was born in vizag
 I love python
 I love python
 I am 22 years old
 I am not an experienced programmer
```

How can I achieve it?

This is the code that i tried but was not successful.

```
import datetime
import os
import fileinput

Dir=input("Source directory:")
os.chdir(Dir)

Filelist=os.listdir()

Filename=input("Enter the file name:")
search=input("Enter a pattern you wish to search for:")
now=datetime.datetime.now()
now_string = str(now.strftime(" %d-%m-%Y_%H%M%S.bak"))
x=Filename
y=now_string
Filename=x
fn=x[:-4]
newname=fn+y

with open (Filename,"r")as input_file, open(newname,"x")as outfile:
    for line in input_file:
        if search in line:
            newline=line.replace(line,line+line)
            outfile.write(newline)
```

With this code the outfile is being created as:

```
I love python
I love python
```

But the other lines are getting eliminated!

Comment: Alright. Fantastic problem,. But what have you done to solve it? SO is not a code writing service. If someone does your homework for you, all you'll do is just copy and paste it in your blue book (most likely without even accepting the answer). You don't learn that way.

Comment: Give us a sample or algorithm on how you plan to solve it like you can search on how to read a file (open the doc or stackoverflow) then search for how to see if a string contain the substring you want etc. if you have absolutely no idea try even more basic problem like filter the file for the match substring etc.

Comment: Made some changes to my question by adding the code that I am currently working on. Sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small change:

```
with open (Filename,"r")as input_file, open(newname,"x")as outfile:
    for line in input_file:
        if search in line:
            line=line.replace(line,line+line)
        outfile.write(line)
```

You want to write the line out even if it doesn't have "love" in it - just only once in that case.

A more straightforward modification:

```
with open (Filename,"r")as input_file, open(newname,"x")as outfile:
    for line in input_file:
        outfile.write(line)
        if search in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Here, you literally just write it an extra time when needed.

Comment: It perfectly works! For the line that we are trying to write for an extra time, can we add a Hash symbol in the starting of that line?                                   I love python
#I love python

Comment: Sure, I think you can figure out how to do that. Remember, you can write to the outfile whenever and whatever you want. Please accept the answer if it was helpful for you.